# Get last vector element by reference

Tags: c++

I have the following code that appends a part of a vector to another.

```
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
#include <assert.h>

using namespace std;

void copyVec(const std::vector<double> in, std::vector<double> &out, int start, unsigned int length) {
    assert(start>=0 && in.size()>=start+length);
    out.reserve(length);
    cout << in.at(9) << endl;
    out.insert(out.end(), &in.at(start), &in.at(start+length));
}

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {
    int start = 0;
    int end = 9;
    int window_size = 10;

    // initialize
    vector<double> vec1 = vector<double>(window_size);
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<window_size;++i) vec1[i] = i;
    vector<double> vec2 = vector<double>(window_size);
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<window_size;++i) vec2[i] = i*10;

    // print
    cout << "vec1: "; 
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<vec1.size();++i) cout << vec1[i] << " "; cout << endl;
    cout << "vec2: "; 
    for (unsigned int i=0;i<vec2.size();++i) cout << vec2[i] << " "; cout << endl;

    copyVec(vec1,vec2,start,end);

    // print
    cout << "vec2: "; for (unsigned int i=0;i<vec2.size();++i) cout << vec2[i] << " "; cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I cannot seem to be able to access vec2's last element by reference. 
The output for this example (int end = 9) is

```
size: 10 start: 0 end: 9
vec1: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
vec2: 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
in[9]: 9 &in[9]: 0x186d118
vec2: 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
```

and, of course, for int end = 10 I get an out of range error:

```
size: 10 start: 0 end: 10
vec1: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 
vec2: 0 10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 
in[9]: 9 &in[9]: 0xae1118
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check
Aborted (core dumped)
```

So how should I (efficiently) append the last vector element?

Comment: Why not use `push_back()`?

Comment: Did you try using `push_back`? Also, you are passing input parameter as `const std::vector<double> in`, why not `const std::vector<double>& in`? You would avoid doing unnecessary copies. And also, you aren't inserting your last element by reference, you are inserting the memory location of the last element.

Comment: `out.insert(out.end(), in.begin(), in.end());`

Comment: **Logicrat** Because push_back iterates one by one over all elements, I need to process the operation in the fastest way possible.
@AlgirdasPreidžius you are right about the ref, thanks :)

Comment: @Ata3ias And, do you *know* that it iterates over the elements? How did you test it? As Described [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/push_back/), the complexity of `push_back` is constant, and not O(n), which means that it doesn't iterate over the vector.

Comment: Who told you `push_back` iterates over all elements? Thats not true.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was that push_back would be used in a loop, which is something I try to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

Your insert should use iterator directly:

```
out.insert(out.end(), in.begin() + start, in.begin() + (start + length));
```

Answer (score 1):

The correct function will look like

```
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

//...

void copyVec( const std::vector<double> &in, 
              std::vector<double> &out, 
              std::vector<double>::size_type start, 
              std::vector<double>::size_type length ) 
{
    assert( in.size() >= start + length );

    out.reserve( out.size() + length );

    out.insert( out.end(), std::next( in.begin(), start ), 
                           std::next( in.begin(), start + length ) );
}
```

The first parameter is declared as constant reference. You should reserve memory for the destination vector taking into account its current size.
It is better to use own iterators of the vector instead of the raw pointers.
`start` and `start + length` specify a range like `[start, start + length )`

For example to copy the entire vector you can write

```
copyVec2b(vec1, vec2, 0, vec1.size() );
```

In general you may not write in the function like

```
cout << in.at( start + length ) << endl;
```

because index `start + length` is not included in the range of copied elements.

You may write

```
if ( length != 0 ) cout << in.at( start + length - 1 ) << endl;
```